# Access Criteria currently Month and next Month

Tags: ms-access

I need to access criteria Currently Month and Next Month

For example : For Today i need 01.04.15 to 31.05.15 but next Month ill need 01.05.15 to 31.06.15

I wrote to criteria this code but i could not get any solution

**

> BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(Date()); Month(Date()); 1) AND
>   DateSerial(Year(Date()); Month(Date()) + 2; 0)

**

if you have a solution about this problem. Please Share with me

Thanks

Y.Ö.

Comment: `0` is invalid day of month

Comment: The OP has an active discussion @ http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=276297 Please either explain here or there what exactly is the problem. @4dmonster, using a **Day** of 0 will tend to take one off the month in the DateSerial function.

Comment: 31 is not a valid day in June.

Answer (score 1):

```
Between DateSerial(Year(Date()); Month(Date()); 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()); Month(Date()) + 2; 0)
```

is correct, so perhaps you just don't have any data within this range.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it. What happens when current month is Nov & Dec then month + 2 = 13 or 14 and not a valid month. Hence, you will need a IIf statement to handle the year being advanced to next year and to handle the Year and the month accordingly. Also, think of the Day again you will need a IIF statement to handle  months ending 28, 30 and 31.

Comment: Isn't it taken care by the Year(), Month() and Date() functions?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was wrong how Access handle the Yearend and the month. Here's some more info. that was posted on https://access-excel.tips/; So; I am not taking the credit.

> Unlike first date of month, we cannot directly input “31” in the day argument because every month has different number of days. Instead we can find the first day of next month and then minus 1 day. Access is very clever that when you add 1 month to December, the year also adds 1, so this trick also works for year end. The formula below returns the last date of current month.
>
> ```
> DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+1,1)-1
> ```
>
> We can also simply this formula using 0 in the day argument instead of using -1. 0 returns the last date of previous month.
>
> ```
> DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) + 1, 0)
> ```